# How to update rows value by Move table rows up and down - Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to rearrange milestones listing up and down by button click or drag and drop.

How to interchange values of input text (rows) after clicking on button or drag and drop by JavaScript.

Any suggestion ?

```html
<table id="wpMilestoneTable" class="tabelle dataTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="10px">
            <col width="800px">
                <col width="70px">
                    <col width="70px">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr class="tabelle_headline">
            <th colspan="2">
                Milestones
       <span class="blue">*</span>
                </span>
                <div style="display: none;"></div>
            </th>
            <th>
                Target Date
       <span class="blue">*</span>
                </span>
                <div style="display: none;"></div>
            </th>
            <th>
                Completed Date
      </span>
                <div style="display: none;"></div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       

    <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="top"><span class="milestoneFldIndex" style="width: 18px;"><b>1.</b></span>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="MILESTONE_TEXT_1" id="MILESTONE_TEXT_1" versioning="true" style="width: 100%;">TEST</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
   
   <span id="msTargetDate_1" style="width: 50px;"><span id="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_1_2">
   
   <input type="hidden" name="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_1_2_cal" id="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_1_2_cal" value="2015-08-06" versioning="true"><span id="dspl_MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_1_2" style="width: 80px;">08/06/2015</span><img id="trigger_MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_1_2" src="/images/calendar.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;"><img src="/images/calendar_delete.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;">
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td><span id="msCompletionDate_1" versioning="true" style="width: 50px;"><span id="MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_1_3"><input type="hidden" name="MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_1_3_cal" id="MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_1_3_cal" value="undefined--undefined"><span id="dspl_MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_1_3" style="width: 80px;"></span><img id="trigger_MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_1_3" src="/images/calendar.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;"><img src="/images/calendar_delete.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;">
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
       

    <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="top" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span class="milestoneFldIndex" style="width: 18px;"><b>2.</b></span>
                <br><img src="/images/icons/ba_remove.gif" name="deleteMilestone2" style="cursor: pointer;">
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                <textarea name="MILESTONE_TEXT_2" id="MILESTONE_TEXT_2" versioning="true" style="width: 100%;">TET4 </textarea>
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span id="msTargetDate_2" style="width: 50px;"><span id="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_2_4"><input type="hidden" name="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_2_4_cal" id="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_2_4_cal" value="undefined--undefined" versioning="true"><span id="dspl_MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_2_4" style="width: 80px;"></span><img id="trigger_MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_2_4" src="/images/calendar.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;"><img src="/images/calendar_delete.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;">
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
  
  <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="top" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span class="milestoneFldIndex" style="width: 18px;"><b>3.</b></span>
                <br><img src="/images/icons/ba_remove.gif" name="deleteMilestone3" style="cursor: pointer;">
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                <textarea name="MILESTONE_TEXT_3" id="MILESTONE_TEXT_3" versioning="true" style="width: 100%;">TEST5 </textarea>
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span id="msTargetDate_3" style="width: 50px;"><span id="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_3_6"><input type="hidden" name="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_3_6_cal" id="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_3_6_cal" value="undefined--undefined" versioning="true"><span id="dspl_MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_3_6" style="width: 80px;"></span><img id="trigger_MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_3_6" src="/images/calendar.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;"><img src="/images/calendar_delete.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;">
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span id="msCompletionDate_3" versioning="true" style="width: 50px;"><span id="MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_3_7"><input type="hidden" name="MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_3_7_cal" id="MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_3_7_cal" value="undefined--undefined"><span id="dspl_MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_3_7" style="width: 80px;"></span><img id="trigger_MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_3_7" src="/images/calendar.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;"><img src="/images/calendar_delete.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;">
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
  <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="top" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span class="milestoneFldIndex" style="width: 18px;"><b>4.</b></span>
                <br><img src="/images/icons/ba_remove.gif" name="deleteMilestone4" style="cursor: pointer;">
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                <textarea name="MILESTONE_TEXT_4" id="MILESTONE_TEXT_4" versioning="true" style="width: 100%; color: rgb(136, 136, 136);">Milestone Description</textarea>
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span id="msTargetDate_4" style="width: 50px; color: rgb(136, 136, 136);"><span id="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_4_8"><input type="hidden" name="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_4_8_cal" id="MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_4_8_cal" value="undefined--undefined" versioning="true"><span id="dspl_MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_4_8" style="width: 80px;"></span><img id="trigger_MILESTONE_TARGET_DATE_4_8" src="/images/calendar.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;"><img src="/images/calendar_delete.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;">
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span id="msCompletionDate_4" versioning="true" style="width: 50px; color: rgb(136, 136, 136);"><span id="MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_4_9"><input type="hidden" name="MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_4_9_cal" id="MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_4_9_cal" value="undefined--undefined"><span id="dspl_MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_4_9" style="width: 80px;"></span><img id="trigger_MILESTONE_COMPLETION_DATE_4_9" src="/images/calendar.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;"><img src="/images/calendar_delete.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;">
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
  
  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use datatables sorting plugin  https://datatables.net/